# Added validations using Formik, but the error is not showing up when I click submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I created a form to upload file using formik. I want to add validations if the user submit the form without selecting any file then the error will show up. But the error is not showing.

Formik code :

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize={true}
  initialValues={{}}
  onSubmit={callUploadFileApi}
  validate={validate}
  validateOnChange={false}
  validateOnBlur={false}
>
  {(props) => (
    <Form>
      <ErrorMessage
        name="file"
        component="div"
        className="alert alert-warning"
      ></ErrorMessage>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <label className="form-label">
          Upload file below (max file size : 200MB)
        </label>
        <Field
          className="form-control form-control-lg"
          id="formFileLg"
          type="file"
          name="file"
          onChange={onFileChangeHandler}
        />
      </fieldset>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-2">
          Share
        </button>
      </p>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>;
```

```
function validate() {
  console.log(state.length);
  let errors = {};
  if (state.length === 0) {
    errors.file = "error";
  }
  console.log(errors);
  return errors;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Formik
  enableReinitialize={true}
  initialValues={{
    file: null // Set initial file value as null
  }}
  onSubmit={callUploadFileApi}
  validate={validate}
  validateOnChange={false}
  validateOnBlur={false}
>
  {(props) => (
    <Form>
      <ErrorMessage
        name="file"
        component="div"
        className="alert alert-warning"
      ></ErrorMessage>
      <fieldset className="form-group">
        <label className="form-label">
          Upload file below (max file size: 200MB)
        </label>
        <Field
          className="form-control form-control-lg"
          id="formFileLg"
          type="file"
          name="file"
          onChange={(event) => {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            props.setFieldValue('file', file); // Update form field value
          }}
        />
      </fieldset>
      <p>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-2">
          Share
        </button>
      </p>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>;

function validate(values) {
  let errors = {};
  if (!values.file) { // Check if file is not selected
    errors.file = "Please select a file";
  }
  return errors;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).